# Impact of lagged values on identity variable

Tags: time-series, econometrics

Let's say I'm working with the following simplified macroeconomic accounting identity

```
 Y_t = C_t + I_t + G_t,
```

meaning that GNP in time `t` equals consumption in `t`, `C_t`, plus investment in `t`,`I_t`, plus government spending in `t`, `G_t`.

I'd like to study the impact of past government spending on current consumption, that's

```
 C_t = f( G_{t-1}, G_{t-2}, ... )
```

so I can make a statement like **"past government spending accounts for x% of current consumption"**. What techniques should I use to run such an analysis while still meeting the equation identity above? Thank you.

Comment: When studying causality, you have to first establish it. You have an endogeneity question here: whether the consumption impacts government spending or not? I'm assuming this is some kind of course work. You better consult with your macro professor on these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a linear relationship between current consumption and past government spending, and assume a stochastic relation (otherwise you should not be asking this question in CV), you will have

$$Y_t \equiv C_t + I_t + G_t$$
$$C_t = a + \sum_{i=1}^k\beta_kG_{t-i} + u_t$$

Combining your model becomes

$$Y_t = a + \sum_{i=1}^k\beta_kG_{t-i} + G_t+I_t+u_t$$

which is a standard [distributed-lag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lag) formulation, rather than a time-series model (for which we expect lagged dependent variables in the RHS).

If we want to view the above as a regression specification,

$$Y_t = a + \sum_{i=1}^k\beta_kG_{t-i} + \beta_{0}G_t+\gamma I_t+u_t$$

we have two a priori restrictions on the parameters, $\beta_{0} = \gamma =1$.

Estimating such a regression, the fitted values plus the residuals will always equal the dependent variable, thus respecting the initial identity. The residuals are to be interpreted as consumption fluctuations, while the constant term is the average value of the part of the consumption that does not depend on past government spending (essentially, the constant term is the mean value of the error term).

Comment: I can't upvote your answer, but do appreciate the details you've provided, thank you.

Comment: Don't worry, just get on with the work.